# Python Text Analysis with TextBlob -- Reading lines from The Office TV Show

Tags: python

I have a Jupyter notebook that allows a user to type in a phrase and the program will 'guess' which Office character it resembles.

Here is a link to the github [repo](https://github.com/jpf5046/text-analyzer/blob/master/The%20Office%20-%20Text%20Analyzer.ipynb)

I have the following littered throughout my code:

```
the_office_raw_script['polarity'] = the_office_raw_script['line_text'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).sentiment.polarity)

the_office_raw_script['scores'] = the_office_raw_script['line_text'].apply(lambda x: analyser.polarity_scores(x))
```

and the following, which is the prediction part:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_upsampled['line_text'], df_upsampled['speaker'], random_state = 0)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()

X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
```

I have some examples of output, which is AWESOME! (so happy i got this far)

```
print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["hard working beet farmer"])))
```

the above prints `dwight`

```
print(clf.predict(count_vect.transform(["that's what she said"])))
```

the above prints `pam` which is totally wrong because michael says 'that's what she said' over 15 times throughout the series.

**Two Questions**

How would I go above making my script into a function, would that be worth it?

How do I somewhat ~hardcode~ some inputs? If someone types in 'that's what she said' or a variation thereof I want it to always print `michael`?